# libxml2.0 missing when configuring val(2)ide before compiling

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, vala

when running ./waf configure i got the following error:

Checking for libxml-2.0 >= 2.5.0            : Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found

I cant find libxml-2.0.pc so im lost in the dark.

How do I solve this?

Running elementary os freya -stable

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `libxml2-dev`. You might also wish to install the package `apt-file`, which can be used to search for files that are not installed.

Comment: Well, I already installed libxm12-dev. I have search after libxml-2.0.pc with "sudo find -name libxml-2.0.pc" with no results so I am still lost in the dark.

apt-file is new to me. I feel a bit ashamed as should have been clever enough to google "find file in package ubuntu" Thank you for giving me the tip and thank you for being so kind.